# Find number of possible triplets (including duplicates) of elements of Array in linear time?

Tags: c

I tried using the nCm function to find all combinations but for large numbers it fails

```
int fact(int num)
{
    if (num == 1 || num == 0)
        return 1;
    return num * fact(num-1);
}

int nCm(int num, int base)
{
    int result;
    return result = fact(num) / (fact(num - base)*fact(base));
}
```

where `base = 3` and num can be anything so for large num it fails. I cannot use bigInteger library so please help

Comment: You can calculate `n!/(n-b)!` without calculating `n!`. Also, you can calculate factorials iteratively, rather than recursively. Finally, if `num` can be *anything* (e.g. Graham's number), then you are doomed to failure.

Comment: If you really have too you can create your own type , being able to hold a number on how much bytes you need. It is up to you for the implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you consider that division for a moment, you'll see that the `(n-b)!` term is common to both numerator and denominator (*i.e.* they cancel out).

You just need to think of `n!` as:

```
n * (n-1) * (n-2) * ...  * (n-b+1) * (n-b)!
```

Now you can calculate the result without any division or large intermediate values (which could overflow), and you can also do it without recursion.